# Check if the vector iterator is valid, in special case, NOT a general solution, c++

Tags: c++, vector

I want to check if a vector iterator is valid.

I have a vector with few thousands entries (objects). The object has an iterator ,as a  private variable , to another same  type  object.

The function which set this iterator I want to check the validity of the input iterator.
In case of error I will stop smoothly everything and I print information in order to find the bug.

Example

```
class Element
{
public:
    int set_my_it_parent(std::vector <Element>::iterator  my_it_parent);
    int get_my_it_parent(std::vector <Element>::iterator  &my_it_parent);
    Element();
    virtual ~Element();
private:
    std::vector <Element>::iterator my_it_parent;
    bool is_it_my_it_parent_fill;
};

//========================================

int Element::set_my_it_parent(std::vector <Element>::iterator my_it_parent_input)
{
    int error_number=0;
    my_it_parent=my_it_parent_input;
    is_it_my_it_parent_fill=true;
    return error_number;
}
```

The class  normalized has a vector of the Elements, and use the  Element::set_my_it_parent

```
class normalized
{
public:
   std::vector <Element> elements_vector;
   normalized();
   virtual ~normalized();
};
```

I am thinking the following solution

```
int Element::set_my_it_parent(
   std::vector <Element>::iterator my_it_parent_input,
   std::vector <Element> &elements_vector
)
{
   std::string message;
   int error_number=0;

   std::vector <Element>::iterator  my_it;
   bool is_it_ok=false;
   for(my_it=elements_vector.begin();my_it!=elements_vector.end();my_it++)
   {
       if(my_it_parent_input==my_it)
       {
        is_it_ok=true;
        break;
       }
   }
   if(!is_it_ok)
   {
       error_number=-330;
       return error_number;
   }
   my_it_parent=my_it_parent_input;
   is_it_my_it_parent_fill=true;
   return error_number;
}
```

I just check and it is working. This solution adds a loop. I will be very happy to see some elegant solutions, thank you for your time.

ps. I am not an English native speaker...

Comment: Why are you not just using an index here? Testing them is trivial...

Comment: You cannot check whether an iterator is valid, *ever*. There are no special cases that make it possible.

Comment: And what do you mean "if its valid" ? You better *know* whether it is valid already. From whence it came, any activity that invalidates it should be logistically accounted for so you don't have to "check" it. You already know: i.e. that dude modified my container, so this iterator is crap now.

Comment: `set_my_it_parent` has undefined behaviour. You cannot compare an invalid iterator with anything (even with itself). In fact you can do pretty much nothing with an invalid iterator. Everything potentially interesting is UB.

Comment: Various implementations of the Standard Library support *checked iterators* as far as I know. Those can use internal knowledge about the implementation of `vector` or implementation-defined behaviour to allow such checks. What implementation do you use? Maybe it already has some implementation of checked iterators that just needs to be activated..

Comment: @dyp, I am using Ubunt 64 bit  g++

Comment: @dionadar  Ok I am going to use index instead of iteration,
 I am going to replace complex variables like the following...


std::vector< std::vector<Element>::iterator > *  html_output_iterator_vector_tmp;
std::vector< std::vector<Element>::iterator > html_output_iterator_vector_tmp_level0;